# Is i915 the right driver for my TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] GPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 21.10, mesa, i915

I just upgraded from 20.04 on an old laptop to 21.10 on a new one. The old one used the proprietary NVidia graphics driver - the new one uses i915. My GPU setup:

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:184 memory:603c000000-603cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

On my old laptop, when I opened "Software and updates", I could choose to replace the Nouveau driver with a proprietary NVidia one, but when I open Software and updates on my new machine, it says "There are no futher drivers available" and "No proprietary drivers are in use".

I'm having trouble getting my secondary display to display anything (it *is* detected - there's just no signal), and one of the first things to do is to figure out if the right driver is in use...

Comment: No, it's a completely fresh install.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific: As I remember it, the Nouveau driver had *horrible* performance compared to the proprietary driver. Is this the same with the i915 driver? Will I get seriously improved performance with another driver?

Comment: Well, thank you, @Nmath, I guess that that was the answer, I was looking for :-)

Comment: N.B. - The driver is correct but the version, kernel dependent, might not be adequate. If your Intel CPU is of the 10th or 11th generation it should have good enough support with the latest kernel available for Ubuntu 20.04 (5.13 at the time of this writing); if 12th generation you may need a newer one.

Comment: It says "11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8" so i guess I'm good ;-)